# Turbo Sort Sorting upto 10^6 using Counting Occurrence in C

Tags: c, sorting

We need to take inputs upto 10^6 and sort them.

So i intialize whole array for zero on paper this code works but the problem i figure out it is that,Every Array index is not intialized to zero which cause the problem can you help me why every Index of array is not intialized to zero?

```
int main()
{
      unsigned int j,i=0,k,t=0,n,input,flag;
    unsigned int a[10^6]={0};//with this method still give garbage value
    scanf("%d",&n);
    flag=0;
    for(k=n;k>=1;k--)
        {

            scanf("%u",&input);
            a[input]=a[input]+1;
            if(input>flag)
            {
                flag=input;
            }
        }
        while(i<=flag)
        {
            if(a[i]>0)
            {
              while(a[i])
              {
                  printf("%u\n",i);
                  a[i]=a[i]-1;
              }
            }
            i++;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

In case you want to know question is here
[Click here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT)
[you can see here i check fresh array for first 25 values and this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFxDT.png)

Comment: This is why using such competition sites are really bad at teaching programming. [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read instead, and you should pretty quickly find out what the problem is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg intializing with zero is not the problem i intialized it doesn't work either see my image.when puting here i made mistake but in actual it is intialzied with zero

Comment: `a[10^6]=0;` --> `a[1000000]={0};`

Comment: The other commenters are right: look up the `memset` function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY this way my codeblock compiler stops responding

Comment: change to `static` or allocate by `malloc`.

Comment: Did you know that `10^6=12`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks buddy code working like charm.Thanks for your help with static unsigned int a[1000000]={0} is fine and all intialized with zero .Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by BLUEPIXY in short replies

with using

```
static unsigned int a[1000001]={0};
```

in the intialization part.
The code is accpeted.
Execution time=0.19 sec